# Can i use Equals To (Comparison Operator) for comparing Images in Sikuli?

Tags: jython, sikuli, image-compression, comparison-operators

The below code has been used. I believe that because of the comparison operator, the error pops up.

I need to match a screenshot and compare it with the present image.

```
while(1):
  if (imgA == imgA):
    click(X)                             #Close the Window
  else:
    click(Y)                             #Error Message
    break
```

Comment: I developed a Sikuli-powered application that utilizes their Java API. However, I work with images almost entirely after converting them to Base64 strings. It's great for file management, among other advantages. You could experiment with that and set your own criteria for string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The Sikuli keyword you are looking for is exists(). Check the [docs](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.exists) for more detailed information.

To dig further into your question, I'd consider something like the following:

```
if exists('img_a.png', 10):
    click(x)
else:
    click(y)
```

This will wait 10 seconds for your screenshot. As soon as that image is detected it will move into the if block and execute the command(s). If the image is not found after 10 seconds it will move the else block and execute those command(s).

Also, note that the docs mention that exists() supports Patterns and Strings. You can call out the image by it's name, or you can provide more detailed pattern information. For example:

```
searchRegion = Region(x, y, w, h)

if searchRegion.exists(Pattern('img_a.png').exact(), 10):
    click(x)
else:
    click(y)
```

The above script prescribes a region to search and checks for an exact match of that image within the given region. You can change .exact() to .similar(0.90) to adjust the match tolerance. 0.01-0.99 are valid matches, with .exact and .similar(0.99) being functionally the same.